# Conventional margins and font size for a (big) thesis in computer science

Tags: margins, fontsize, geometry

I am writing a big thesis in computer science. I use `geometry` package for the page layout.

For the font size, I hesitate between 11pt and 12pt. Let's assume I use 12pt here.

Because I want the page to be wide enough to hold long formulas, I think `2cm` to the left/right border is fine. But if I set `\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}`, I feel that the top margin and the bottom margin are too small.

Are there some conventional parameters for them, for a thesis (or a book) in computer science, where long formulas don't have to be split very often (wide enough)? I just want to make it pleasant and easy to read...

Also, which one is better between 11pt and 12pt?

Comment: Use the `hmargin=2cm` option: this leaves  `vmargin` untouched. In my opinion, 11pt is fine (it's often the size chosen by professional typographers, thouh this may depend on the font used in document).

Comment: Then, do you think `2cm` is the conventional horizontal margin? I just want the document to be wide enough, but i am not sure if `2cm` is the norm...

Comment: Don't forget the referee may want to add annotations in the margin. I have no ideas for computer science. I only can tell you for  ordinary (traditional) books  and traditional French typography, I would use as an optional argument to  geometry; `[textwidth=157.75mm, textheight=234mm, marginratio={4:6,5:7}, nomarginpar] `. Also, don't forget the inner margin has to be about half the outer margin.